# How set field values for a firestore documents as a json

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

During the execution of this code I want to create a json with contain as a value the document field (key and value) of a subdocument.

```
function getobjectItemsById(id){
  var objectItemsRef = db.collection(collectionName).doc(id).collection(subCollection);
  let object_items = [];
  return objectItemsRef.get()
      .then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(item => {
              let object_item = {};
              object_item.id = item.id;
              object_item.object_item = item.data();
              console.log(item.data()); 
              object_items.push(object_item);
          })
          return object_items;
      })
}
```

But when I return this object in output whit:

```
console.log(objects)
```

My output:

> [object Object] [object Object]

How can I receive correct key and value?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: `console.log(JSON.stringify(objects))`